# How to extract different items from a text and list them in AutoHotkey

Tags: text, extract, autohotkey

I am new at autohotkey and any code including activity :) I want to extract some parts from the below sample haystack  and list them in a message box with order of appearence as a list ( if one item is found more than one it will be listed only one time, if it makes things easier they appear side by side no other listing item is placed between same list items )

---

My Sample Haystack:

Aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer elementum erat
 vitae urna pellentesque **perm-anen-t1** condimentum. Curabitur vestibulum vehicula **perm-anen-t1** porttitor. Ut ac tellus et tellus
 auctor ornare. Aliquam volutpat purus in augue sagittis, eget bibendum lacus cursus. In vitae lorem
 ultrices, sollicitudin **prot-esto-r7** nunc non, fringilla erat. Suspendisse **qual-ifie-d6** at vehicula leo. Mauris imperdiet augue
 nec erat suscipit, eget aliquet nunc auctor. Sed felis eros, dictum non tincidunt ac, tempus et nunc.

Mauris vehicula **auto-moti-v9** molestie fermentum. Morbi consectetur eros eget erat **auto-moti-v9** aliquet, non dictum ipsum **auto-moti-v9** sodales.
 Duis scelerisque mi non interdum condimentum.

Vivamus rutrum neque nunc, consequat porta **susp-ende-d7** urna vehicula ac. Donec et tristique massa. Suspendisse dictum
est at dui posuere condimentum. Etiam eleifend pharetra tortor, nec mollis magna congue at. Mauris libero
nisi, posuere **numbe-r1fi-t3** sit amet velit sit amet, consectetur scelerisque nulla. Maecenas elementum purus in sem
lacinia, sit amet facilisis arcu ornare. Donec **numbe-r1fi-t3** tempus dignissim lacinia. Pellentesque lacinia imperdiet
quam, eu rutrum arcu. Maecenas et est eu nibh suscipit vulputate nec quis massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum
primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean eu sagittis orci. Integer
consequat nec ligula non **noven-ber1-25** tincidunt. Vivamus vel venenatis **noven-ber1-25** nibh. Quisque pharetra orci id pharetra
laoreet. Phasellus augue enim, tincidunt **noven-ber1-25** pellentesque mi ac, fringilla auctor orci.

---

My Desired List:

```
1. perm-anen-t1

2. prot-esto-r7

3. qual-ifie-d6

4. auto-moti-v9

5. susp-ende-d7

6. numbe-r1fi-t3

7. noven-ber1-25
```

I tried `loop, RegexMatch, RegexReplace, InStr` etc. but can't manage. In tutorial it talks about an array but when I use `RegexMatch` match1 is listed right but match 2 is empty. It can be very useful if one can solve this using `Regular Expressions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
src:="Aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur "
. "adipiscing elit. Integer elementum erat vitae urna pellentesque "
. "perm-anen-t1 condimentum. Curabitur vestibulum vehicula perm-anen-t1 "
. "porttitor. Ut ac tellus et tellus auctor ornare. Aliquam volutpat purus "
. "in augue sagittis, eget bibendum lacus cursus. In vitae lorem ultrices, "
. "sollicitudin prot-esto-r7 nunc non, fringilla erat. Suspendisse "
. "qual-ifie-d6 at vehicula leo. Mauris imperdiet augue nec erat suscipit, "
. "eget aliquet nunc auctor. Sed felis eros, dictum non tincidunt ac, tempus "
. "et nunc.`r`nMauris vehicula auto-moti-v9 molestie fermentum. Morbi "
. "consectetur eros eget erat auto-moti-v9 aliquet, non dictum ipsum "
. "auto-moti-v9 sodales. Duis scelerisque mi non interdum condimentum.`r"
. "`nVivamus rutrum neque nunc, consequat porta susp-ende-d7 urna vehicula "
. "ac. Donec et tristique massa. Suspendisse dictum est at dui posuere "
. "condimentum. Etiam eleifend pharetra tortor, nec mollis magna congue at. "
. "Mauris libero nisi, posuere numbe-r1fi-t3 sit amet velit sit amet, "
. "consectetur scelerisque nulla. Maecenas elementum purus in sem lacinia, "
. "sit amet facilisis arcu ornare. Donec numbe-r1fi-t3 tempus dignissim "
. "lacinia. Pellentesque lacinia imperdiet quam, eu rutrum arcu. Maecenas et "
. "est eu nibh suscipit vulputate nec quis massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum "
. "primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean "
. "eu sagittis orci. Integer consequat nec ligula non noven-ber1-25 "
. "tincidunt. Vivamus vel venenatis noven-ber1-25 nibh. Quisque pharetra "
. "orci id pharetra laoreet. Phasellus augue enim, tincidunt noven-ber1-25 "
. "pellentesque mi ac, fringilla auctor orci.", pattern:="O)(\S*-\w*-\S*)"

MsgBox, % 262 . ((retResult:=SomeFunc(src, pattern)) ? 208:160)
      , % retResult ? "Result:":"Oops!"
      , % retResult ? RTrim(retResult, "`n"):"No matches"
;      , % (retResult ? 3:0) . .5

SomeFunc(p*)
{
   Static a:=[]
   Local oVar:=cond:=outList:=""

   While, RegExMatch(p.1, p.2, oVar, oVar.Pos(1) ? oVar.Pos(1)+oVar.Len:1)
   {
      Loop, % ObjMaxIndex(a)
         cond:=False
      Until, cond:=(a[A_Index]=oVar.Value)
      `(!cond) And a[A_Index]:=oVar.Value
   }
   For k, v In a
      outList.=(A_Index<=9 ? "0"A_Index:A_Index)". "v "`n"
   Return, outList
}
```